# Encountered unsupported property VpcId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-iam

I am writing a cloud formation template that install SSM agent in EC2. but when i upload the template in Cfn. I got the error called Encountered unsupported property VpcId.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: This Template Create an EC2 in public subnet with SSM.

Parameters:
  VPCId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
    Default: vpc-04ef73b29000f4f54 

  PublicSubnet01Block:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    Description: SubnetId of an existing subnet (for the primary network in your Virtual Private Cloud VPC)
    Default: subnet-0699037225107e8b2 

Resources:
  SSMIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore


  EC2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref SSMIAMRole

  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref EC2InstanceProfile
      ImageId: ami-0aa7d40eeae50c9a9
      VpcId: !Ref VPCId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet01Block
      InstanceType: t2.micro
```

I am not sure what else to try. Here is the template I am working with..

Comment: Please consult the documentation before posting questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory, `VpcId` is not a supported parameter for EC2 instances in cloudformation according to the [reference documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html). Instead, you can specify a `SubnetId` (which it seems like you've done!) and that will place it in the VPC you want, since subnets are associated with VPCs.

Comment: yes...its my mistake